# RTC : HTTP Filtered Value Set Error - Connection to http://localhost:8888 refused

Tags: rtc

I have created  HTTP Filtered Value Set provider and in configuration i am providing the URL - "http://localhost:8888/example_data/makers.xml" which works fine when accessed thru browser , i can see the xml file. I kept the xml file under tomcat ROOT dir "apache-tomcat-7.0.65\webapps\ROOT\example_data\makers.xml"
When i hit Test button it could not retrieve the XML and shows error as "Connection refused". Can anyone pls tell me what can be the issue here ?

By the way The log contains below-

```
[HttpFilteredValueSetProvider]Retrieving values from HttpConnector...
[HttpConnector]Ignoring invalid SSL certificates
[HttpConnector]Retrieving XML document...
[HttpConnector]Could not retrieve XML document
```

Thanks

Akshay P.

[image]